# prevent multiple submit with exhaust map in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the best practice or how to use exhaust Matp to prevent multiple submissions ? like for example when user spam the SAVE button ? for example based on the sample code below , how do we handle it that it would only submit 1 at a time even the user spam or click the save button hundred times. Thanks.

How do we example apply exhaust map on the ff code below so that even user will click the button multiple times only 1 request will go even the user spam the click save.

#html code

```html
<ng-template #editButtons>
  <div class="flex" *ngIf="isEditing">
    <app-page-section-cards-btn
      [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.cancel"
      (btnClickEvent)="cancelEdit()">
    </app-page-section-cards-btn>
    <app-page-section-cards-btn
      [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.save"
      (btnClickEvent)="saveDeal()">
    </app-page-section-cards-btn>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

#ts code

```
 saveDeal(){
    this.isLoading = true;
    if(!this.isExistingDeal){     
      const dealTypeValues = {
        "id": 0,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "summary": this.dealPLSFormFields.summary,
        "mlasId": this.dealPLSFormFields.partner,
        "startDate": "estimatedOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.estimatedOtherRevenue,
        "descriptionOfOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.descriptionOfOtherRevenue,
        "totalMonthlyRentAndFees":this.dealPLSFormFields.totalMonthlyRentAndFees,
        "buildOutCostReimbursement":this.dealPLSFormFields.buildOutCostReimbursement,
        "dealId": 0,
        "startDateString": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.startDate),
        "endDateString":  AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.endDate),
      } 
     
      const payload = {
        "id": 0,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": null,
        "firmTermRemaining": null,
        "firmTermAdded": null,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "status": null,
        "capitalContribution": null,
        "parentCloneId": null,
        "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
        "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
        "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
      }
      this._dealService.createDeal(payload)
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          this.isLoading = false;
          this._notificationService.showSuccess('Deal was successfully created.');
          if(res.isSuccess){
            this.refreshDealDetailsPage(res.data);
          }  
        },
        err=>{
          console.log('Error creating deal')
        }
      )
    }else{

      const dealTypeValues = {
        "id": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.id,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "summary": this.dealPLSFormFields.summary,
        "mlasId": this.dealPLSFormFields.partner,
        "startDate": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.startDate),
        "endDate": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.endDate),
        "securityMonitoringMonthly": this.dealPLSFormFields.securityMonitoringMonthly,
        "rent": this.dealPLSFormFields.rent,
        "cam": this.dealPLSFormFields.cam,
        "supportServicesFee": this.dealPLSFormFields.supportServicesFee,
        "estimatedOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.estimatedOtherRevenue,
        "descriptionOfOtherRevenue":this.dealPLSFormFields.descriptionOfOtherRevenue,
        "totalMonthlyRentAndFees":this.dealPLSFormFields.totalMonthlyRentAndFees,
        "buildOutCostReimbursement":this.dealPLSFormFields.buildOutCostReimbursement,
        "dealId": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.dealId,
        "startDateString": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.startDate),
        "endDateString":  AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealPLSFormFields.endDate),
      } 

      const payload = {
        "id": this.dealData.id,
        "name": this.dealPLSFormFields.dealName,
        "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": null,
        "firmTermRemaining": null,
        "firmTermAdded": null,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "status": this.dealData.status,
        "capitalContribution": null,
        "parentCloneId": null,
        "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
        "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
        "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
      }
      
      this._dealService.updateDeal(payload)
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          if(res.isSuccess){
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.refreshDealDetailsPage(res.data);
          }  
        },
        err=>{
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log('Error updating deal')
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With .pipe(debounceTime(500)) is ok. The request not will sent after 500ms.
What's the problem with the code?

Comment: I would just create a check to see if whatever needs to get changed actually changed. I don't think this is a good use case for exhaust map. Either that or debounceTime like in your example depending on if you don't want any unnecessary saves or just want to prevent quick successions.

Comment: I already added debounce time  , but when I click the save multiple times a lot of data is saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- Create a **boolean** that you flip when data changes and when you save
- Hold an object, **lastSaved** in memory to compare to the object to be saved

Then use either of these to check if a save is necessary before actually saving.